# Implement mouse over and mouse click event for specified screen region

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some specified region on the screen (not on the form, but on the screen), for example, it's region in the upper-right corner of the screen.

```
Rectangle specifiedRegion = new Rectangle(*,*,*,*);
```

I want to implement mouse over and mouse click event for that region. When mouse was over that region, some button or picture appeared in that region. If user clicked that region, mouse click event executed.

How can I do it ? Please, provide some code or good links.

C#, VS 2008, .net 2.0, 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a warning before we get started that the solution isn't going to be pretty, AFAIK you cannot do this completely within managed code.

Now then:

In order to intercept messages to other application you are going to need to make some native calls using User32.dll. If you want to figure all this out the hard way you want to start with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Assuming you aren't a masochist there is a nice C# library I found on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx) that will make life much easier than manually trying to intercept those messages yourself. Setup a callback for the mouse messages with the X and Y coordinates for the mouse position you can determine if it is within the bounds of your `Rectangle` using its `Contains` method.

```
specifiedRegion.Contains(mouseLocation); //where mouseLocation is a Point
```

User32 also has the functions you will need to get a Device Context for the screen:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr dc);
```

To get the DC for the screen use the following call to `GetDC`:

```
IntPtr screenDC = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
```

With this DC we can get our C# `Graphics` object and start drawing.

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(screenDC);
```

Remember to dispose the `Graphics` object and release the DC after you finish with it or you will have a memory leak.

```
g.Dispose();
ReleaseDC(screenDC);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to do this.  Just make a panel control in the region you want this to happen.  Use the mousemove and mouseclick events of the panel control to capture your inputs, and you can even copy whatever image you want directly to the panel.  This encapsulates the entire operation within the panel, avoiding the need for handling outside the panel class.

Comment: Wouldn't this need to be an *invisible* panel located on a separate, *invisible* form?  Doesn't sound that simple to me. (There are ways to do it, though)